# Hiding content accessibly now that clip is deprecated?

Tags: css

At the moment I'm using the following code to hide content accessibly. However, according to MDN the clip property is deprecated and will be removed.

```
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
```

What is best practice to hide content accessibly now?

Comment: You can use `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`  to hide element.

Comment: `display:none` typically will hide content from a screen reader, which in some cases you don't want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `clip-path` with proper vendor prefixes, along with `clip` as the fallback, because `clip-path` is not supported in all browsers at this time as shown in [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

The CSS would look something like this:

```
.offscreen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 0px,0px 0px, 0px 0px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 0px,0px 0px, 0px 0px);
  overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

I've also added a codepen for you to [see it in action](http://codepen.io/longmatthewh/pen/eJRBVK).

Answer (score 5):

In your CSS block, add `clip-path: inset(50%);` (after `clip`).

Answer (score 0):

```
opacity: 0
height: 0
height: 0;
```

will do the trick if you do not want the Element to dissapear from the screen reader.

You might also have to use

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

to prevent spacing errors.

Just saw that `caniuse` in [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34723602/3880255), well opacity will [always work](http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity) `:P`